# How to get referral url of a visitor

Tags: php

I am trying to get the referral url of visitors coming to my site. I have tried using

```
<?php

  $refer = $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"];

   echo $refer;

?>
```

But the result is always empty. Can someone please help me.

Comment: have tried using *what*?

Comment: <?php

  $refer = $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"];

   echo $refer;

?>

Comment: its browser set, mine is always blank - you will only know sometimes